# Where is the new Hyperkube repo now?

Tags: kubernetes, hyperkube

It looks like Hyperkube is not available in kubernetes repo since 1.17, but there is nowhere mentioned about where it is now.

Reference in 1.17:
Hyperkube will now be available in a new Github repository and will not be included in the kubernetes release from 1.17 onwards (#83454, @dims)

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://github.com/adelina-t/hyperkube) repository?

Comment: I'm afraid it is not the official one. I've got the answer on github. Link below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the answer from Github. Here is the link.
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/91897